# entrypoint.prod.sh file not found (Docker python buster image)

Tags: python, django, docker, deployment, docker-compose

I'm getting this issue with my entrypoint.prod.sh file that it doesn't exist even though I have echoed "ls" command and it shows me that the file is present in the right location with the right permissions but still docker isn't able to find it. I have tried many solutions but none are working. Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you guys need any extra information from me.

so this is my main docker-compose.staging.yml file: -

```
version: '3'

services:

  django:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker-compose/django/Dockerfile.prod
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - static_volume:/app/django/staticfiles
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sparrowteams
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sparrowteams
      - POSTGRES_DB=sparrowteams
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - .:/data

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/django/staticfiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - django

  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.staging.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  static_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
```

Then I have my Dockerfile.prod: -

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.1-buster as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc && pip install psycopg2 && apt-get -y install nginx

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./backend .

# install dependencies
COPY backend/requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.1-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/app
ENV APP_HOME=/app/django
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
COPY --from=builder /app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY docker-compose/django/entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

RUN chmod +x $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

# copy project
COPY ./backend $APP_HOME

RUN echo $(ls -la)

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh  && \
        chmod +x $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/django/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

and then finally I have my entrypoint.prod.sh file (Which is actually giving an error that it doesn't exist.)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

gunicorn SparrowTeams.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

My nginx/vhost.d/default file: -

```
location /staticfiles/ {
  alias /app/django/staticfiles/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

nginx/custom.conf: -

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

nginx/dockerfile: -

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy
COPY vhost.d/default /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default
COPY custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
```

My project structure looks something like this: -

```
- SparrowTeams (Main folder)
    - backend
        - SparrowTeams (Django project folder)
    - docker-compose
        - django
            - Dockerfile.prod
            - entrypoint.prod.sh
    - nginx
        - vhost.d
            - default
        - custom.conf
        - dockerfile
    - .env.staging
    - docker-compose.staging.yml (Docker compose file that I'm running)
```

Comment: I've tried making a minimal dockerfile that takes a shell script file and runs it using bash and that works fine. Can you edit your code so it becomes reproducible for us? Right now we're missing a lot of stuff if we want to try it ourselves.

Comment: @HansKilian what would you like me to add? The project structure etc?

Comment: I would like you to remove things that are irrelevant. For instance your whole build step should be irrelevant since it shouldn't make a difference as to whether Docker can find the shell script.

Comment: So, the thing that you guys suggested about the entrypoint file worked that was changing the volume name. But now, I am facing another issue which is that my containers build up okay and site is server runs perfectly but when I pull my new changes in my backend directory which is a submodule inside my main docker repo for the project my project doesn't get updated I'm guessing because the volume is already mounted and it keeps running the same code that was used to build it. Can you guys suggest me something for this. Let me know if I can explain this more clearly or if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have a volume that you mount to `/app` in your docker-compose file. That overrides the `/app` directory in your container and that's why it can't find the script.

```
  django:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker-compose/django/Dockerfile.prod
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app     <==== This volume
      - static_volume:/app/django/staticfiles
```

You can either change the name of the directory you mount `./backend` to (that's what I'd do), or you can place your app in another directory in your final image. The problem is caused by both of them being called `/app`.

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot man. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can I persuade you to mark my answer as the accepted solution so I get my Internet points? :)

Comment: (The `static_volume` mount will similarly overwrite your application's `staticfiles` directory with the contents of the volume.  If you're depending on Docker automatically copying image contents into the volume, this only happens the first time the container runs; later on Docker will never update it.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you. I'll change that too. I think I'll just remove this volume.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I was thinking about this on the way home in the train and maybe it'd be better to have the volume mappings needed for the build in the build part of your Dockerfile (as VOLUME statements). Then you'd only need the volumes for running the container in the docker-compose file.

Comment: So, the thing that you guys suggested about the entrypoint file worked that was changing the volume name. But now, I am facing another issue which is that my containers build up okay and site is server runs perfectly but when I pull my new changes in my backend directory which is a submodule inside my main docker repo for the project my project doesn't get updated I'm guessing because the volume is already mounted and it keeps running the same code that was used to build it. Can you guys suggest me something for this. Let me know if I can explain this more clearly or if you have any questions